# Динамическая загрузка контента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю динамическую загрузку контента на сайте, столкнулся с такой проблемой: при попытке загрузить(перейти на) определенную динамическую страницу в лог выбрасывается

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined at _loadPage (main.js:16)
at HTMLAnchorElement._navigate (main.js:35)
at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4430)
at HTMLBodyElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4116)`

При этом если ввести например прямой адрес `example.com/about` то страница открывается без каких либо ошибок.
Код кнопки перехода:

```
        <li>
          <a href="blog" data-menu="blog" data-link="ajax" <?php echo ($pageMenu == 'blog') ? ' class="active"' : '' ?>>
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
            <span class="menu-text">Блог</span>
          </a>
        </li>
```

main.js

```
var app = (function() {

    // Загрузим конфиг из data/config.json
    var config = {};

    var ui = {
        $body: $('body'),
        $menu: $('#menu'),
        $pageTitle: $('#page-title'),
        $content: $('#content')
    };

    // Загрузка контента по странице
    function _loadPage(page) {
        var url = 'templates/' + page + '.html',
            pageTitle = config.pages[page].title,
            menu = config.pages[page].menu;

        $.get(url, function(html) {
            document.title = pageTitle + ' | ' + config.siteTitle;
            ui.$menu.find('a').removeClass('active');
            ui.$menu.find('a[data-menu="' + menu + '"]').addClass('active');
            ui.$pageTitle.html(pageTitle);
            ui.$content.html(html);
        });
    }

    // Клик по ссылке
    function _navigate(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        var page = $(e.target).attr('href');

        _loadPage(page);
        history.pushState({page: page}, '', page);
    }

    // Кнопки Назад/Вперед
    function _popState(e) {
        var page = (e.state && e.state.page) || config.mainPage;
        _loadPage(page);
    }

    // Привязка событий
    function _bindHandlers() {
        ui.$body.on('click', 'a[data-link="ajax"]', _navigate);
        window.onpopstate = _popState;
    }

    // Старт приложения: привязка событий
    function _start() {
        _bindHandlers();
    }

    // Инициализация приложения: загрузка конфига и старт
    function init() {
        $.getJSON('/data/config.json', function(data) {
            config = data;
            _start();
        });
    }

    // Возвращаем наружу
    return {
        init: init
    }
})();

// Запуск приложения
$(document).ready(app.init);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста где я накосячил.

Comment: `config.pages[page]` - говорит нет такого

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev странно, файл есть, в конфиге он прописан, если по кнопке ткнуть "открыть в новой вкладке" всё работает.

Comment: Для поиска проблемы выводите по клику в консоли что в какой момент что содержит. Например в `_loadPage` выведите `console.log(config, config.pages[page])`. Я подозреваю что у вас проблема именно в конфиге, нет в нем нужной страницы или путь внутри него неправильный

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev я тут заметил что если ткнуть примерно между значком и самой надписью контент прогружается и ошибки нет, скорее всего дело в самой кнопке. Теперь не совсем понятно куда прилепить код чтобы он корректно работал на всей кнопке.

Comment: сильно сомневаюсь